# Android EXIF data always 0, how to change it?

Tags: android, image, camera, orientation, exif

I have an app that captures photos using the native `Camera` and then uploads them to a server. My problem is that all the photos have an EXIF orientation value of 0, and this messes up the display elsewhere.

How can I change the EXIF orientation? I'm not looking for a way to correct it for every circumstance, just change it to a different value.

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Note 4

I tried this solution that sets the camera orientation before taking photos: [Setting Android Photo EXIF Orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23205759/setting-android-photo-exif-orientation)

```
Camera c = Camera.open();
c.setDisplayOrientation(90);

Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
params.setRotation(0); // tried 0, 90, 180
c.setParameters(params);
```

but it doesn't influence the resulting EXIF data, its still always 0

I also tried these solutions where the image is rotated after it is taken: [EXIF orientation tag value always 0 for image taken with portrait camera app android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245556/exif-orientation-tag-value-always-0-for-image-taken-with-portrait-camera-app-and)

and while this rotates the photo, the EXIF orientation is still always 0.

I also tried setting the EXIF data directly: [How to save Exif data after bitmap compression in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23762133/how-to-save-exif-data-after-bitmap-compression-in-android)

```
private Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        final File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE, "");
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);

            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(pictureFile.toString());
            exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, "3");
            exif.saveAttributes();

            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();

            //upload photo..
        }
    }
}
```

but EXIF Orientation is still 0 after uploading.

I have also looked at these solutions:

[Exif data TAG_ORIENTATION always 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574561/exif-data-tag-orientation-always-0)

[How to write exif data to image in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732781/how-to-write-exif-data-to-image-in-android)

[How to get the Correct orientation of the image selected from the Default Image gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478765/how-to-get-the-correct-orientation-of-the-image-selected-from-the-default-image)

[how to set camera Image orientation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28379130/how-to-set-camera-image-orientation)

but they all involve correcting the orientation by rotating, which doesn't influence the EXIF data, or setting the EXIF data directly which doesn't seem to work.

How can I change the file's EXIF orientation data from 0 to 3?

UPDATE:

here is my upload code:

```
Bitmap sBitmap = null;
final File sResizedFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE, "_2");
try {
    sBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(pictureFile), null, options);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e("App", "[MainActivity] unable to convert pictureFile to bitmap");
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}

// ... compute sw and sh int values

Bitmap sOut = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(sBitmap, sw, sh, false);
Bitmap rotatedBitmap = rotateBitmap(sOut, 3);
FileOutputStream sfOut;
try {
    sfOut = new FileOutputStream(sResizedFile);
    rotatedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, sfOut);
    sfOut.flush();
    sfOut.close();
    sBitmap.recycle();
    sOut.recycle();
    rotatedBitmap.recycle();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("App", "[MainActivity] unable to save thumbnail");
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
// upload small thumbnail
TransferObserver sObserver = transferUtility.upload(
            "stills/small",        /* The bucket to upload to */
            filename + ".jpg",     /* The key for the uploaded object */
            sResizedFile           /* The file where the data to upload exists */
);
```

Comment: on which device you are trying ?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy Note 4

Comment: @Cbas, is the _"EXIF orientation value of 0"_ **before** or **after** you upload to online bucket? I just tested Amazon's AWS buckets and they retain EXIF **after upload**. You must be using a different bucket-based server (eg: Google Cloud), right? After your first code snippet you say _"it doesn't influence the resulting EXIF data, its still always 0"_ **so it's a code issue**? Then after your second code snippet you say _"but EXIF Orientation is still 0 **after uploading**."_ **so it's an upload/server issue?** Please confirm if EXIF value always 0 even before upload or only after upload?

Comment: @VC.One its 0 before the upload, definitely a code issue

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out my code was able to set the EXIF data, but there is a discrepancy between how Android interprets this data and how iOS and Chrome on a Mac (where I was checking the resulting file) interprets it.

This is the only code needed to set EXIF orientation:

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(pictureFile.toString());
exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, "3");
exif.saveAttributes();
```

However, setting `3` shows up as `0` on iOS and the image is sideways in Chrome.

setting `6` shows up as `3` on iOS and the image looks right in Chrome.

Comment: +1 for progress on own issue. You should have mentioned the Android / iOS testing issue. Only thing I can add is that iOS is Big Endian and Android is Little Endian. I'll expand in an Answer box...

Answer (score 30):

As you can see, the The EXIF information is not reliable on Android (especially Samsung devices).

However the phone SQL database holding the references to Media object is reliable. I would propose going this way.

Getting the orientation from the Uri:

```
private static int getOrientation(Context context, Uri photoUri) {
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
            new String[]{MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION}, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.getCount() != 1) {
        cursor.close();
        return -1;
    }

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int orientation = cursor.getInt(0);
    cursor.close();
    cursor = null;
    return orientation;
}
```

Then initialize rotated `Bitmap`:

```
public static Bitmap rotateBitmap(Context context, Uri photoUri, Bitmap bitmap) {
    int orientation = getOrientation(context, photoUri);
    if (orientation <= 0) {
        return bitmap;
    }
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(orientation);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, false);
    return bitmap;
}
```

If you want to change the orientation of the image, try the following snippet:

```
public static boolean setOrientation(Context context, Uri fileUri, int orientation) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION, orientation);
    int rowsUpdated = context.getContentResolver().update(fileUri, values, null, null);
    return rowsUpdated > 0;
}
```

If you set the orientation of the image, later it will be constantly set at the correct orientation. There is need to make use of `ExifInterface` later, because the image is already rotated in proper way.

If this method is not satisfactory, then you could try [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28891244/6507689)

Comment: Yes, you are correct we should get the orientation of Uri data picked from gallery. Thanks Your solution worked for me!!!

Comment: You definitely deserved more than 10 votes for this answer. Thank you

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.database.Cursor.getCount()' on a null object reference` unfortunately

Comment: @jujka high chance your file is not in the MediaStore images table. Insert it before querying for orientation value, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28249682).

Comment: @amartin1911 we do a litttle necro-coding answering 4 y.o. questions what adds absolutely zero value to this conversation

Answer (score 12):

You have accepted your own answer as solution. My rant is just useful side-info, anyways...

The *"However..."* in your Answer suggests while you now know the cause, you don't have a fix.

> Turns out my code was able to set the EXIF data, but there is a
>   discrepancy between how Android interprets this data and how iOS...
>   interprets it.

This could be an endianness issue. You can try manually changing the endianness setting of Exif by opening your jpeg in a hex editor and finding...

- The bytes `45 78 69 66` (makes "Exif" text) followed by two zero bytes `00 00`.
- Then it should be `49 49` (makes "II" text) which means read data as little endian format.
- If you replace it with `4D 4D` (or "MM" text) then the reading side
  will consider data as big endian.

Test this in iOS to see if numbers are now correct.

[image]

and regarding this...

> However, setting `3` shows up as`0` on iOS and the image is sideways in
>   Chrome.
>  
>   Setting `6` shows up as `3` on iOS and the image looks right in Chrome.

Only thing I can add is that <strike>iOS</strike> Mac is **Big Endian*** and Android/PC is **Little Endian**. Essentially Little Endian reads/writes bytes as right-to-left whilst Big Endian is opposite.

In binary : `011` means **3** and `110` means **6**. The difference between 3 and 6 is simply the reading order of those bits of ones & zeroes. So a system that reads as `zero-one-one` gets a result of **3** but the other Endian system will read a byte with same bits as `one-one-zero` and tell you result is a **6**. I can't explain why *"3 shows up as 0"* without a test file to analyse bytes but it's a strange result to me.

`</end rant>`
`<sleep>`

**note*: While Macs are Big Endian, double-checking says iOS uses Little Endian system after all. Your numbers still suggest a Big vs Little Endian issue though.

Answer (score 3):

Refer this GitHub project https://github.com/pandiaraj44/Camera. It has the custom camera activity where EXIF TAG_ORIENTATION was handled correctly. You can clone the project and check. For code details please refer https://github.com/pandiaraj44/Camera/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/pansapp/cameraview/CameraFragment.java

Comment: ExifInterface: Invalid image: ExifInterface got an unsupported image format file(ExifInterface supports JPEG and some RAW image formats only) or a corrupted JPEG file to ExifInterface. when i running your code

Answer (score 3):

There is one class to read and update these information of images.

To update the attributes you can use like this

```
ExifInterface ef = new ExifInterface(filePath);
            ef.setAttribute(MAKE_TAG, MAKE_TAG);
            ef.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, orientation+"");
            ef.saveAttributes();
```

and for reading you can use like this

```
 ExifInterface exif = null;
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(absolutePath+path);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
```

I hope it will help you